# App crashing on launch: libc.so (missing), libjsc.so (missing)

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using react native 0.61.5 and hermes is disabled. I have tested in the devices available with me and the app is working fine but in the firebase crashlytics its crashing in different devices.

> Crashed: Thread :  SIGSEGV  0x0000000000000010
> #00 pc 0x77e3837748 libjsc.so
> #01 pc 0x77e3883fe8 libjsc.so
> #02 pc 0x7893602a28 libc.so

Comment: Facing same issue

Comment: @Sarath did you find any solution for this